# Java XSLT How can I escape French, German AND Greek in the same document?

Tags: java, xslt, encoding

I am successfully reading Microsoft DOCX files with Java using the java.util.zip classes. I start by translating MS XML into what I need using XSLT.  Since I am outputting HTML, I notice that most of the obvious characters are correctly escaped by XSLT without me having to do anything, such as ndash, ldquo, rdquo, egrave, eacute, uuml, auml etc.  I then use Java regular expressions to do further processing on the XSLT output.

My problem is that in addition to French and German, I also have Greek.  The Greek is not escaped by XSLT, but appears correctly in the XSLT output, and if I edit the resulting file (with eclipse, or even with notepad) the unescaped greek is displayed correctly.  BUT...

When I work on the XSLT output with java code, it scrambles the Greek, and any page I save has the usual random characters you see if the page is encoded wrongly.

Clearly I am not encoding this the right way.  I have been trying to do it in UTF-8 since all my ISO-8859-1 characters are escaped.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?  Is there any way persuade XSLT to escape the Greek characters for me as well as those it already does?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is processing HTML with regular expressions...

Comment: Thank you for your somewhat cryptic comment, which by itself is not very helpful. Do you mean there is a BAN on doing that?  Is there some documented restriction?  Or is it just your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the output encoding in the xslt to "us-ascii"? That way it should escape all non-ascii characters using their corresponding character entities.

However, the real problem is working on the resulting XML/HTML using regular expressions. You should try to do this processing using xml and encoding aware tools, or even as part of the xsl transformation. Most Java XSLT processors even allow calling of Java function from within the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the `disable-output-escaping` attribute of `xsl:value-of` and `xsl:text`.

```
<xsl:value-of select="expression" disable-output-escaping="yes|no" />
```

As the default value is "no", you have to actively set it to "yes" to get escaped characters in the output.

Comment: I worked around the problem by rewriting my code that reads and processes the Microsoft XML so that it is encoding aware up to a point when I can definitively escape ANY characters that do not appear in ISO-8859-1.  After that I know it is safe to use regular expressions. As a result my app can generate 800+ html pages, a total of over 4 million words, in less that 50 seconds.  One day I may get out my JAXB book again but I don't know when that will be.  Having written JAXB code I estimate it would take 3X to 5X the lines of code.